# VM doesn't pick up any ip address

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, virtualization, dhcp

I'm running virtualbox in bridged mode on a windows host.

`ifconfig` returns this:

[image]

Here's the `etc../interfaces file`:

[image]

here's the output of `ifconfig -a`:

[image]

here's the output of `route`
[image]

**How can I force it to grab an IP address from the `dhcp`?**

Comment: Are using IPv6 or IPv4 on your machine?

Comment: @Mitch im sorry i dont know how do i find out?

Comment: @dee yes it is indeed

Answer (score 1):

Is windows host using DHCP? It is not the MAC address filetring on router's side coming into action? Why not then use NAT settings on VM setup?

Comment: great idea, will try to do the NAT setup right now, can you please tell me whats the difference?

Comment: NAT setup did indeed assign an IP, however when i try to ping that IP from the host machine, i am getting DESTINATION UNREACHABLE

Comment: Then the virtualisation acts as yet another router and routes traffic to separated subnet dedicated for virtual machines.

Comment: ups.. something bad should be with your virtualised OS. Did you restart it?

Comment: Try to restart networking `sudo service networking restart` or to go with eth0 down and up `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`.